# curl hangs on link download, browser works ok

Tags: bash, apache, web, curl, web-scraping

I try to download this url http://www.sourcecode.se/sokoban/levels?act=dnl_text&file=100Boxes.slc it downloads fine on browser, but it doesn't work with

`curl -v http://www.sourcecode.se/sokoban/levels?act=dnl_text&file=100Boxes.slc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double quote your URL ,there are character like `&` in the URL. Which will sent curl into background with partial URL

```
curl -v "http://www.sourcecode.se/sokoban/levels?act=dnl_text&file=100Boxes.slc"
```